# Getting Model property of non-associated View object

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

When I am in the View of a specific object, I can acces all the instances by this loop in the View:

```
 @foreach (Reservation r in Model) { }
```

But How to implement the same foreach cycle with Ski Class, which is not associated with this View?

Comment: Add the Ski class to your view model ;-)

Comment: So the only way is to make a list of Skies? @Stefan

Comment: Do you have a view that implements the `Ski` class?

Comment: I added public `virtual ICollection<Ski> skies { get; set; }` into the Reservation Model. Still cant use the foreach... @Stefan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add whatever you need access to to your model. It is common to create specific ViewModel classes that are specific to one or a few views and provide access to whatever they need. In your case it would have Reservations as well as Ski data.

Example:

```
public class ReservationViewModel
{
  public List<Reservation> Reservations { get; set; }
  public List<Ski> Skis { get; set; }
}
```

Now in the View you can foreach over Model.Reservations, as well as over Model.Skis.

Comment: I added public `virtual ICollection<Ski> skies { get; set; }` into the Reservation Model. Still cant use the foreach... @ssmith